# What does arrow function '() => {}' mean in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I was reading the source for [ScrollListView](https://github.com/ryanseddon/ScrollListView/blob/master/src/main.js) and in several places I see the use of `() => {}`.

Such as on line 25,

```
this.cellReorderThreshold = () => {
    var ratio = (this.CELLHEIGHT*this.cellsWithinViewportCount)/4;
    return ratio < this.CELLHEIGHT ? 0 : ratio;
};
```

line 31,

```
this.container.addEventListener('scroll', () => this.onScroll(), false);
```

line 88.

```
resizeTimer = setTimeout(() => {
    this.containerHeight = this.container.offsetHeight;
}, 250);
```

Is this a shorthand for `function` and if it differs in any way, how so?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is the new arrow syntax of ES6. It differs by the treatment of `this`: `function` gets a `this` according to the *calling* context (traditional semantics), but the arrow functions keep the `this` of the context of *definition*.

see http://tc39wiki.calculist.org/es6/arrow-functions/

Comment: Please note browsers compatibility https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Mozilla compat tables don't seem to be updated often. Check our table for up-to-date support — https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#arrow_functions

Answer (score 6):

> ECMAScript 6 **`arrow function`** introduce, Arrow **`(=>)`** part of the **`arrow function`** syntax.

Arrow functions work differently from traditional JavaScript functions. I'm found this article explain how is different from traditional function: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/09/10/understanding-ecmascript-6-arrow-functions/