# Vue component data function - the is empty

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a Vue.js component defined as following:

```
module.exports = Vue.component('folder-preview', {
    props: ['name', 'path', 'children', 'open'],
    template: `...
    `,
    methods: mapActions([
    ]),
    computed: mapState([
    ]),
    data: ()=> {
        console.log(this);
        return {
            collapsed: (this.open !== 'true')
        }
    }
});
```

Basically, I'm trying to keep `collapsed` as data local to the component, but take the value passed in the prop as the initial value. However, it seems like `this.open` is always undefined. In fact, console.logging `this` prints an empty object, and I can't seem to figure why.

Am I getting something wrong?

Comment: What happens if you print `this.open` in `created` (add a property `created` like how you add `props`, `data` and `computed`, and like `data`, `created` takes a function)?

Comment: why can you not use open in you props as collaosed and set the value in parent element

Comment: @kevguy in created `this` is also empty

Comment: @usrNotFound what sets the collapsed is the component itself. The parent shouldn't care / doesn't need to be aware of it. It's internal to the component

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VueJS: why is "this" undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43929650/vuejs-why-is-this-undefined)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your code is subtle: you've declared data as an arrow function.

As covered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29030779/1470607), arrow functions get `this` from the context of definition, while regular functions get `this` from the calling context. Making `data` an arrow function means it won't receive the component scope correctly.

When declared as a regular function that doesn't scope `this` off, the component works fine.

```js
Vue.component('sample', {
  props: ['open'],
  template: '<div>{{collapsed}}</div>',
  data() {
    return {
      collapsed: this.open !== 'true'
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <sample open="true"></sample>
</div>
```