# jQuery why is $(this) in callback function "window"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, window, this

I was about to make delete button for my to-do list code. 
this is my code in `<script>`

```
  var del = $("<ion-icon name='trash'></ion-icon>").click((e)=>{
    var p = $(this).parent();
    p.remove()
    console.log(this)
  })
```

and I got log like this in browser console.

`Window {parent: Window, opener: null, top: Window, length: 0, frames: Window, …}`

now I found another one is way to use `$(e.target)` 
but I'm still curious why $(this) in callback function is "window".
I'm waiting for your great answer :) thx !

- and this is what I wanna do in my code

```
$('#task').click((e)=>{

  var task = $("<li class='task'></li>").text($('#enter-task').val())

  var del = $("<ion-icon name='trash'></ion-icon>").click((e)=>{
    var p = $(this).parent();
    p.remove()
    console.log(this)
  })

  task.append(del)

  $("#tasklist").append(task)

})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does arrow function '() => {}' mean in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29030747/what-does-arrow-function-mean-in-javascript)

Comment: actually, not. but thx :)

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery [.parent()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_parent.asp) method return the parent of a span element, which is shown in the documentation.

Your icon is probably inside a span element and when you call the method parent() `var p = $(this).parent();`  you are targeting the [Window](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp) object.

Comment: umm, but you can see what I used `console.log(this)`