# Why I can't use "this.innerHTML" in this situation?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.drum');

for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
    playSound(buttons[i].innerHTML);
  });
}
```

Can someone please explain to me why I can't use this.innerHTML to reference to my button?

Thanks!

Comment: A `=>` function will not get its own local `this` value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28798330/arrow-functions-and-this

Comment: Duplicate of [What does arrow function '() => {}' mean in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29030747/what-does-arrow-function-mean-in-javascript)