# my arrow functin is not working truly , Why?

Tags: javascript

everyone  , i traydi create a arrow function but its not working in my way

console.log(cevabiKontrolEt("c"); //Ture //resalt

console.log(cevabiKontrolEtme("c"); //False //resalt

what is the different between them

> Blockquote

```
let soru5={
    soruMetni: "hanig soru jaavadan gelir",
    cevapSecenekleri: {
        a: "node.",
        b: "banbası",
        c: "atası"
    },
    dogruCevap: "c",
    cevabiKontrolEt :function(cevap) { return cevap === this.dogruCevap; },
    cevabiKontrolEtme :(cevap) =>   cevap === this.dogruCevap 
    
 
}
console.log(cevabiKontrolEt("c"); //Ture //resalt
console.log(cevabiKontrolEtme("c"); //False //resalt
```

Comment: this has been anwered multiple times https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29030747/what-does-arrow-function-mean-in-javascript

Comment: below code is worked finally :)   `let soru5={
    soruMetni: "hanig soru jaavadan gelir",
    cevapSecenekleri: {
        a: "node.",
        b: "banbası",
        c: "atası"
    },
    dogruCevap: "d",
    cevabiKontrolEt :function(cevap) { return cevap === this.dogruCevap; },
    cevabiKontrolEtme : (a) =>  a == soru5.dogruCevap ,
      buneki:"c",
      
 
}

console.log(soru.soruMetni);
console.log(soru5.cevabiKontrolEt("c"));



console.log(soru5.soruMetni);
console.log(soru5.cevabiKontrolEtme("c"));
`